# Unwanted entry in the database every time I try to do an insert Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'll try my best to explain my current situation so please bear with me.

I really need your help in this because I'm seriously running out of ideas. I was trying to do some queries where the user will not be able to input duplicate entries to the database.

I have 3 databases named Semester, Prereq, and Coreq.

In my view I have this table where I display 5 columns. Three from the Semester database(College Code, Semestral Year, and Subject Code) which I joined(left) with Prereq and Coreq(they both have College Code, Semestral Year, and Subject Code). One column from Prereq(which is prereq) and one column from Coreq(which is coreq). Please note that in both Prereq and Coreq they don't have any unique column.

Now in my php application that uses codeigniter, the user needs to input in either Prereq or Coreq.

Upon testing on some random variable on the Prereq form, the said random variable seem to get stuck every time I enter something to the other form which is Coreq.

So let's say I input something like ABC in the Prereq. That ABC would always be there every time Input something to the Coreq which really shouldn't be happening. Like every time I try to add an entry using the application, for example I choose to add a Coreq named Math101 to some college code with its subject code, in my table view the new row entry with Math101 has a spooky Prereq ABC even though I only entered on the Coreq form.

I have an input page where the user gets to input in two separate forms. They get to add either on the Coreq form or the Prereq form via select tags. These select tags get populated from the same 3 tables by json encode and jquery. The values they can input are College Code, Subject Code, Coreq/Prereq. They can only input in one form at a time. It has two buttons in which if you press Add Coreq, the Prereq form hides via Jquery and vice-versa so I find it very weird that a value I placed before is always there. Kind of spooky.

Here's the codes I was testing out inside my Model:

```
public function setCoreq(){
    $f1 = $_POST['sy'];
    $f2 = $_POST['college'];
    $f3 = $_POST['subjcode'];
    $f4 = $_POST['coreq'];

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COLLCODE, SY, SUBJCODE, COREQ FROM College_co_req"
          . " WHERE COLLCODE ='$f2' AND SY = '$f1' AND SUBJCODE = '$f3' AND COREQ = '$f4'");
    $num = $query->num_rows();

    if($num==0){
        $this->db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO College_co_req VALUES('$f1', '$f2', '$f3', '$f4')");
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

public function setPrereq(){
    $f1 = $_POST['sy'];
    $f2 = $_POST['college'];
    $f3 = $_POST['subjcode'];
    $f4 = $_POST['prereq'];

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COLLCODE, SY, SUBJCODE, PREREQ FROM College_pre_req"
          . " WHERE COLLCODE ='$f2' AND SY = '$f1' AND SUBJCODE = '$f3' AND PREREQ = '$f4'");
    $num = $query->num_rows();

    if($num==0){
        $this->db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO College_pre_req VALUES('$f1', '$f2', '$f3', '$f4')");
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

The boolean will then get passed to my Controller and my controller redirects the user to either an error_input page(if it returns false) or the view page that shows the table with 5 columns(when true).

Here's my controller:

```
public function insertCoreq() {
    $check = $this->triune_colleges_model->setCoreq();

    if($check == false){
        $this->load->view('input_error');
    }else{        
        $data['results'] = $this->Model->subject_all();
        $this->load->view('table_view', $data);
    }
}
public function insertPrereq() {
    $check = $this->triune_colleges_model->setPrereq();

    if($check == false){
        $this->load->view('input_error');
    }else{        
        $data['results'] = $this->Model->subject_all();
        $this->load->view('table_view', $data);
    }
}
```

The input_error page technically has the same things from my input page. The only difference is that it has a div tag with a class of error which displays a message that disappears via a jquery.

I tried going into the console and disabling cache as well as going through the trouble of deleting my browsing history, cookies, autofill, and passwords, for the whole day. But the spooky Prereq entry still persists.

The only time the spooks happened was when I placed the

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT COLLCODE, SY, SUBJCODE, COREQ FROM College_co_req"
      . " WHERE COLLCODE ='$f2' AND SY = '$f1' AND SUBJCODE = '$f3' AND COREQ = '$f4'");
$num = $query->num_rows();

if($num==0){
    $this->db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO College_co_req VALUES('$f1', '$f2', '$f3', '$f4')");
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

code from the insertCoreq to the insertPrereq since it was working when I tried it out a few days ago.

Any suggestion/solution is appreciated. Please help x'D

Here's how I display my table on my view if anyone's willing to check it:

```
<?php foreach ($results as $results_item): ?> 
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $results_item['CollCode']; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $results_item['SY']; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $results_item['SubjCode']; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $results_item['Coreq']; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $results_item['Prereq']; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Here's my query from my Model:

```
$this->db->select('college_semester.SubjCode, college_semester.CollCode, college_semester.SY, college_pre_req.Prereq, college_co_req.Coreq');
    $this->db->from('college_semester');
    $this->db->join('college_co_req', 'college_semester.CollCode = college_co_req.CourseCode AND college_semester.SubjCode = college_co_req.SubjCode AND college_semester.SY = college_co_req.SY', 'left');
    $this->db->join('college_pre_req', 'college_semester.CourseCode = college_pre_req.CourseCode AND college_semester.SubjCode = college_pre_req.SubjCode AND college_semester.SY = college_pre_req.SY', 'left');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
```

and here's from my Controller:

```
$data['results'] = $this->Model->subject_all();
$this->load->view('table_view', $data);
```

Comment: Debug, debug, debug. Echo, print_r, var_dump. Find what, then why.

Comment: How though? I have no background on debugging tbh x'D

Comment: use `exit` after printing data

Comment: @Max where should I place it?

Comment: echo "f1=".$f1;echo "f2=".$f2;echo "f3=".$f3;echo "f4=".$f4;exit;

Comment: @Max I've posted how I display my data, where should I put those?

Comment: u ask for the unwanted entry in your database so you should check those data you gonna insert in, and see whether it is the right data you want or not. if its not what you want you should check where they are coming from and see what happen.
sry im not pretty good at english but hope you can understand what im talking about

Comment: Don't worry english also isn't my best language hahahaha. I've var_dumped to check if the passed data are correct and they are, without a hint of doubt, correct.

Comment: so what is the "unwanted" for example: you want "jack" but you got "mark" ?

Comment: Imagine 5 columns. I only wanted to make an entry for one row with only 4 values. I entered 4 values but the row I got has 5 values.

Comment: if you use "INSERT IGNORE INTO College_co_req VALUES('$f1', '$f2', '$f3', '$f4')" in your database will it execute like what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I think I'm close to finding out why it's such a mess, I think it's the view's fault since it doesn't look like it's refreshing every time I insert new datas. Any idea how I can do it?

Comment: so your view didn't refresh after u inserted new data?

Comment: I assume it didn't. I looked at my table and it seems that it exists inside the table of my database

Answer (score 0):

Check for the problem in two areas at time of data insert and data fetch.

1. Have you checked data in both the table in database ? check for the data which you have inserted is exist in both the table or in desired table using database console.
2. check how 'table_view' is populating data. check the query it use to fetch data.

Regards,

Comment: How can I check them? I honestly don't know anything about debugging x'D

Comment: which database are u using ? go to database console and check using select query.

Comment: Okay I've managed to check(pretty much a bunch of var_dumps) on my functions and they seem to be functioning quite well(they returned true). I've also checked if the values are getting passed from my view to my controller and to my Model and they have gotten passed.

Comment: Yes and I've checked my Joined view and it really had inserted the unwanted entry(prereq) even though I've only submitted on my coreq form :'(

Comment: Wait wow, some values are not inserting. It's like it only works for a couple of values, but the moment I try to insert a different set of values it returns null. wtf

Comment: View is not to insert any value it is result set of a stored query on the data. as you told it is showing null value so please check join condition is proper or not and check how data inserted using insert statement.

Comment: I've managed to fix my query and it's now inserting in the database as expected. My last problem now is my view, it doesn't display the new entries I have inserted.